# performing math operation in tikz pgfplot functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I realize it must be something SO basic, but I'm having difficulty figuring out where the problem can possible be.

It seems to me all three of these `\addplot`s should be the same. However, only the first one works as expected (which is a problem, because I'm needing it to perform the calculation.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathparse{1+(6/100)}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick distance=5,
    minor x tick num=4
  ]
    \addplot[smooth,green,domain=0:25] gnuplot [id=plot3] {155*1.06**x}; % works
    \addplot[smooth,green,domain=0:25] gnuplot [id=plot2] {155*(1+(6/100))**x)}; % makes dumb flat line
    \addplot[smooth,green,domain=0:25] gnuplot [id=plot4] {155*\pgfmathresult**x}; % makes some sort of weird parobalic nonsense?
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I can tell I'm not explaining my question very well, so please don't hesitate to direct me to reword or explain something.

Comment: `\pgfmathresult` is heavily used for *any* math operation. So probably, it will be overwritten by the time you use it (to calculate internal domain limit, whatever). I think you are looking for `declare function`?

Comment: Ah, wait, you are using `gnuplot`. You have a closing parenthesis more in the second function, and you need to write `1+(6.0/100)` for `gnuplot`, otherwise the division is integer.You have to use valid `gnuplot` expression there, not l`pgfmath` ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. `\pgfmathresult` is used by almost all the operations in the `pgfmath` layer, so you can use it only immediately after the calculation, or it will be overwritten.
2. When using `gnuplot`, the expression is passed to it with almost no processing, so you have to use `gnuplot` syntax and rules. `6/100` is an integer expression, so it will give zero. Use `6.0/100` or similar tricks to force floating point.
3. You should manually expand the macros *before* passing them to `gnuplot`:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2.72mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\myk}{(1+(6.0/100))}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick distance=5,
        minor x tick num=4
        ]
        \addplot[green,domain=0:25] gnuplot [id=plot3] {155*1.06**x}; % works
        \addplot[smooth,red,dashed,domain=0:25] gnuplot [id=plot2] {155*(1+(6./100))**x}; % makes dumb flat line
        % this trick will "prepare" an expanded "addplot" command into \tmp
        % and then we'll call it. 
        \edef\tmp{\noexpand\addplot[smooth,blue,densely dotted,domain=0:25] gnuplot [id=plot4] {155*(\myk**x)}}
        \tmp;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]